# I think there is something wrong with the system

Tags: discussion, reputation

Please tell me what is wrong as I don't understand.

Here is the situation.

A guy asking why is he [seeing threads unique IDs counting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141285/managedthreadid-keeps-increasing). I am saying — because you are creating new threads and each new thread is taking new number... and he is like — I know they are new I am asking why .NET won't reuse old IDs (from terminated threads)... [and his reason actually — he thinks that ID around 100 is too big a number!]

Well I couldn't be bothered to explain that this is simply preposterous idea. And I didn't say that if he had any idea on programming he wouldn't ask. I was about to walk away as he won't appreciate any help really.

But... I looked at the guy's score and he has 33K SO points.

I mean come on. What might his value for the SO community be if he is asking fifth grade college questions and still getting 33K??

I know life is not fair, yada yada, but that seems too much for me.

**What's the point system is about then? Not knowledge. Then what?**

Edit: he has 36K, I was wrong.

Could you please stop downvoting? this is a discussion if you have something to say let's discuss.

Comment: 5th grade in college? Impressive! I had to go through 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, and 12th before I got there...

Comment: Vote on meta are different: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: 5th grade is a joke form of 6th form. losen up a bit

Comment: @Bobb You can't really post brutal criticism like that, and then ask others to loosen up. If you can't accept criticism yourself, you should consider toning down your question first.

Comment: -1 because this is just a rant without a question or a discussion.

Comment: I don't think this rant of a question has any meaning whatsoever. It just feels like you are taking your frustrations out. I perfectly agree with @slugster's answer below and all the string of comments/posts here but for yours, Bobb.

Comment: No, I can't stop downvoting. This is hilariously juvenile.

Answer (score 21):

He could be experienced in areas other than threading. I have 8,000 points largely thanks to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but I'll probably sound like a total tit if I go ask questions about C++ or iOS programming.

I'm sorry to hear you "couldn't be bothered" to explain why he was misguided. The entire point of Stack Overflow is to share knowledge and understanding. I hope you reconsider and look at that question as an opportunity to share some of your knowledge.

Comment: Anna you understand that basic principle of uniquiness is where every softwar developer should start. it is nothing to do with threads... iOS or C++

Comment: @Bobb I... am not sure what you're talking about there. What principle of uniqueness?

Comment: Right.. sorry.. you didnt get it either.... ok... if you reuse the same ID it wont be unique anymore. your code wont be able to rely on the ID if it could be reused. if you see thread #1 how do you know it is 1st #1 2nd 3d or whatever........

Comment: @Bobb Ahh, you were talking about threads. I thought you were talking about some general software development principle. :)

Comment: you seriously dont see the problem or you are just making fun?

Comment: @Bobb Neither. I have on idea what question prompted you to make this post and talking about threading principles in the comments here would be off-topic at best. It's not an argument that needs to happen here. I was just saying that I was unsure what you were talking about, then you clarified, and I responded to that.

Comment: there is nothing about threading. i said that and you just dont want to see it... unique IDs are everythere. whatever really.

Comment: Unique IDs aren't always necessary. Usually, sure, but plenty of systems exist where IDs are reused. I assumed you were talking about threads since that was the context of your original question...

Comment: We have have highly specialized areas of expertise and broad regions of total tititude (I have to say that I am digging this expression today.). Except Jon Skeet who have only tightly defined areas of modest tititude.

Comment: Bobb: By contrast bash assigns unique job numbers to processes launched from the command line but under some circumstances *reuses the ones previously assigned to finished processes*.

Answer (score 12):

Wow, that is harsh  criticism....

First, let's look at [**your** stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347484/bobb):

> 100 questions
> 28 answers with a total of only **4** upvotes
>
> a grand total of 975 rep from 2+ years of using the site

**Is it at all possible that you have misunderstood the objective of the target question?**

### Edit:

IMVHO it is a nothing question and the answer is inconsequential, it is simply a question about the technical implementation of the ManagedThreadId property which very few people could answer with any authority. Your answer is reasonable but tangential - it doesn't answer the specific question. Don't lose any sleep over it, it happens sometimes.

Comment: no its not possible.

Comment: @Bobb: That's a little... arrogant to make as a definitive statement.

Answer (score 7):

> whats the point system is about then? not knowledge. then what?

Stack Overflow reputation is a fuzzy metric that, to put it simply, measures how much the community trusts you. It's *not* (only) about knowledge, it's a blend of various things, including the relative value of your contributions, your familiarity with the system in general, your sockpuppetry skills, etc.

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48710/alan-kay), for example, has only 3K points, but, trust me, he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: The "guy" who you referred above is "Alan Kay".. one of the several people whom I  respect and look up to... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay.

Comment: @verisimilitude I know, I was trying to make a point that reputation is a completely worthless metric of knowledge.

Comment: :) It's Ok, I misinterpreted it when you said above "he knows what he's talking about".

Answer (score 6):

Reputation is not synonym of how much someone knows, it just tells how much the community trusts in someone.

Consider all these scenarios:

- Expert coder starting a new account
- Newbie that used the site for years
- **User that earned rep only in certain tags where he is good at, then tried new ones**
- User that earned rep in one lucky question/answer with 100+ votes
- etc etc

None of these accurately reflect how much someone knows about anything in particular, it's impossible to tell this out of reputation alone